# Convert characters to date and choose the max date (DB2 SQL statement)

Tags: sql, db2

I have customers database in DB2 (AS400), this is about contracts of customers and all columns are in character format, then i have these columns :

- ID_CNT : character(9)
- UPdate_Date : character(8)
- Description : character(4)

Below a sample of the data :

| ID_CNT | Update_Date | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100002032 | 20180220 | NQSA |
| 100002032 | 20191031 | NQSA |
| 100003519 | 20180210 | SNCF |
| 100003519 | 20191101 | SNCF |
| 100003519 | 20180131 | SNCF |
| 100004657 | 20190412 | LODG |
| 100004657 | 20200513 | LODG |

I would like to chooce the max date (the last date) for each contract ID (ID_CNT).

I use this SQL statement :

```
Select distinct 
ID_CNT, max(date(substr(Update_Date ,1,4) || '-' || substr(Update_Date ,5,2) || '-'|| substr(Update_Date,7,2))) AS Update_Date, Description 
From DB.CUSTOMERS 
group by ID_CNT, Description
```

But it's not work. Someone have any idea what's wrong in my SQL statement ?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't ever worked with AS400, but could you please try CAST( Update_Date AS DATE)?  If it works then SELECT  ID_CNT,MAX(CAST(Update_Date AS DATE))MAX_DATE FROM DB.CUSTOMERS GROUP BY ID_CNT

Comment: Why do you want to convert Update_Date to date? It may be a string but it is comparable as it is because its format is YYYYMMDD.

Comment: I did try CAST before i post my question but it's not work

Answer (score 3):

A much simpler way to convert the value to a date is to use `to_date()`:

```
Select ID_CNT, max(to_date(update_date, 'YYYYMMDD')), Description 
From DB.CUSTOMERS 
group by ID_CNT, Description;
```

Note that `select distinct` is almost never appropriate with `group by`.  And it is unnecessary in this case (but doesn't affect the result set).

However, there is no reason to convert to a date, so this should also work:

```
Select ID_CNT, max(update_date), Description 
From DB.CUSTOMERS 
group by ID_CNT, Description;
```

That is, `MAX()` works just fine on strings (alphabetical ordering) and that is what works.

This, in turn, assumes that the id and description are always the same.  If you want one row per `id_cnt` and all columns from that row with the maximum date, then:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id_cnt order by update_date desc) as seqnum
      from db.customers c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: If OP want's a date, I'd make the conversion after the max...

Comment: Yes, the function MAX() work, but it's my fault if my SQL statement does't worked, because i forgot another colum in my sql code, that column could be different based on the Update_date column, then i made changes and my SQL code work now :     
Select distinct
t0.Update_Date, t0.ID_CNT, t0.Description, t0.STATPROP

From DB.CUSTOMERS t0
INNER JOIN 
(
 Select IDCNT, max(Update_Date) Update_Date
 From DB.CUSTOMERS
 group by ID_CNT
) t1
ON t1.ID_CNT= t0.ID_CNT
and t1.Update_Date= t0.Update_Date

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be storing dates as text, but, that aside, your text dates actually should be sorting correctly already as text.  So the following query should work here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT c.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_CNT, Description ORDER BY Update_Date DESC) rn
    FROM DB.CUSTOMERS c
)

SELECT ID_CNT, Update_Date, Description
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Note: If you really want to view the dates with hyphens separating the components, then you could select the following:

```sql
SUBSTR(Update_Date, 1, 4) || '-' || SUBSTR(Update_Date, 5, 2) || '-' || 
SUBSTR(Update_Date, 7, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is :

```
Select distinct
t0.Update_Date, t0.ID_CNT, t0.Description, t0.STATPROP

From DB.CUSTOMERS t0
INNER JOIN 
(
    Select IDCNT, max(Update_Date) Update_Date
    From DB.CUSTOMERS
    group by ID_CNT
) t1
ON t1.ID_CNT= t0.ID_CNT
and t1.Update_Date= t0.Update_Date
```